prove that LTI system A is a positive iff A is Meltzer matrix
I need to show that LTI system A is a positive system iff A is Metzler.
Reminder: A is positive system if for every $x(0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_+ => x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_+$
I'm trying to prove the => direction, by showing that if A is not Metzler then the system is not positive.
I can use the fact that for small t's we have: $x(t) ≈ x(0) + tẋ(t) = x(0) + tAx(0)$
I was trying to do some manipulation of taking $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ matrix with one non diagonal entry $a_{01}=-2$, meaning: $A=\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

vector $x(0)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$
so i get a vector $x(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
-t \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and therefore x(t) is not positive vector. I'm not sure of this proof. Can you please direct me for the right proof?

It is not enough to take one non-Metzler matrix and show the system is not positive - you must prove it for every non-Metzler matrix. By the way, does $\mathbb{R}_+$ include zero or not? (this affects the difficulty of the proof)

@arkeet , it can include zero entries also. Can you direct my for the right solution?

Hint: You have noted that $x(t) \approx x(0) + tAx(0)$ for small $t$, which you can write as $(I + tA)x(0)$. If $A$ is not Metzler, what can you say about $I+tA$?

@arkeet it's also not Metzler. How that helps me? I tried writing x(t)_i entry when I insert some negative aij and to show that x(0)_i decresses as time increases, but nothing convincing so far.

If $x(t)_i$ decreases, what happens if it starts at zero (e.g. if $x(0)$ is the $j$th basis vector)?

@arkeet if it decreases than the entry becomes negative at some point, but the question remains how to show it indeed decreases? I only know that an entry contains a negative number as part of its sum

Is it enough to show that if A is not a Metzler, than there exists some $x(0)\in \mathbb R^n_+$ such that $x(t)\notin \mathbb R^n_+$?
If A is not Metzler, there are $i\neq j$ such that $a_{ij}<0$.
Choose $x(0)\in \mathbb R^n_+$ such that: $x_k(0)=0,  \forall k\neq j$ and $x_j(0)>0$. For some small $t$, with $()≈(0)+ẋ()=(0)+(0)$ we get $x_i(t)<0$ and the system is not positive.

Thanks for your input!
